# Handling Asynchronous Speech Recognition with Azure Cognitive Services in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to push audio payload to azure STT. I am unsure if I am specifying and instantiating the recognizer correctly, I can not find a good example for my case. This is the error message I am getting:

```
Connected to azure: SessionEventArgs(session_id=9a9e39a5863c4bd49f26fd440af70d1d)
Canceled: SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=9a9e39a5863c4bd49f26fd440af70d1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=ec76038624504f53bb1a53d4175ec5a4, text="", reason=ResultReason.Canceled))
Session stopped: SessionEventArgs(session_id=9a9e39a5863c4bd49f26fd440af70d1d)
```

```py
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import json
import time

class AzureSST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = None
        self.session_started = False

        with open('config_ai.json', 'r') as file:
            self.config = json.load(file)

        # specify the audio format
        self.wave_format = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(samples_per_second=8000, bits_per_sample=16,
                                                    channels=1)
        self.stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(self.wave_format)
        self.audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=self.stream)

        # Set config key and region
        self.speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=self.config['azure_stt']['key'], region=self.config['azure_stt']['region'])
        # Set profanity raw
        self.speech_config.set_profanity(speechsdk.ProfanityOption.Raw)
        # instantiate the speech recognizer with push stream input
        self.speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=self.speech_config, audio_config=self.audio_config)

        # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognize
        self.speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(self.on_session_started)
        self.speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(self.on_message)
        self.speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(self.on_session_stopped)
        self.speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(self.on_canceled)

        # Start continuous speech recognition
        self.speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition_async()



        # Forwards audio RTP packages to azure stream
    def send(self, audio_data_buffer):
        if self.session_started:
            self.stream.write(audio_data_buffer)

    def on_message(self, msg):
        print(msg)

    def on_session_started(self, evt):
        print('Connected to azure: {}'.format(evt))
        self.session_started = True

    def close_connection(self):
        self.speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        print("Connection to azure closed.")

    def on_session_stopped(self, evt):
        print('Session stopped: {}'.format(evt))

    def on_canceled(self, evt):
        print('Canceled: {}'.format(evt))
        

``
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your code and can be able to get the text output with input speech.

**Code** :

```py
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import json
import time
import pyaudio

class AzureSST:
    def __init__(self, subscription_key, region):
        self.session_started = False

        self.wave_format = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(samples_per_second=16000, bits_per_sample=16, channels=1)
        self.stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(self.wave_format)
        self.audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=self.stream)

        self.speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=subscription_key, region=region)
        self.speech_config.set_profanity(speechsdk.ProfanityOption.Raw)

        self.speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=self.speech_config, audio_config=self.audio_config)

        self.speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(self.on_session_started)
        self.speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(self.on_message)
        self.speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(self.on_session_stopped)
        self.speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(self.on_canceled)

        self.speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition_async()

    def send(self, audio_data_buffer):
        if self.session_started:
            self.stream.write(audio_data_buffer)

    def on_message(self, msg):
        print("Recognized:", msg.result.text)

    def on_session_started(self, evt):
        print('Connected to Azure:', evt)
        self.session_started = True

    def on_session_stopped(self, evt):
        print('Session stopped:', evt)

    def on_canceled(self, evt):
        print('Canceled:', evt.reason)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('config_ai.json', 'r') as file:
        config = json.load(file)
    subscription_key = config['azure_stt']['key']
    region = config['azure_stt']['region']

    azure_sst = AzureSST(subscription_key=subscription_key, region=region)

    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 16000

    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    try:
        while True:
            audio_data_buffer = stream.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)
            azure_sst.send(audio_data_buffer)
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        audio.terminate()
        azure_sst.speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
```

**config_ai.json** :

```json
{
    "azure_stt": {
        "key": "<speech_key>",
        "region": "<speech_region>"
    }
}
```

**Output** :

It runs successfully and gave the text output with input speech below,

[image]